# Should all endpoints joined to a multicast group receive data sent to the group?

Tags: c, port, combinations, multicast

If two endpoints are joined to say 100 multicast groups on two ports, now if I am sending data to one group address and port comb(g1,p1), should it not get received by other sockets as well because they are also the member of the group.

If no why not? and if yes then what is wrong with following code?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

void socketCreation(void)
{
  unsigned int i=0;
  u_int    yes=1;

  for(i=0;i<gConfiguration.numSockets;i++)  //200
  {
    if ((gConfiguration.sockArray[i] = WSASocket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP,NULL,0,0))== INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
      printf("\n\t Socket Creation failed with error ::%d::", WSAGetLastError());
      WSACleanup();
      exit(1);
    }
    // Allow Multiple Sockets to use the same PORT number */
    if (setsockopt(gConfiguration.sockArray[i],SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(char*)&yes,sizeof(yes)) < 0) 
    {
      printf("\n\t SetSockOpt for SO_REUSEADDR failed with error ::%d::", WSAGetLastError());
      WSACleanup();
      exit(1);
    }
  }

}

void socketBinding(void)
{
  struct     sockaddr_in addr;
  unsigned int i=0;
  unsigned int j=0;
  unsigned int tempPort =0;
  long localaddr  = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  int k = 0;
  for(i = 0;i<gConfiguration.numPorts;i++)
    {
      addr.sin_port=htons(gConfiguration.ports[i]);
      addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
      addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
      // bind to receive address
      if (bind(gConfiguration.sockArray[i],(struct sockaddr *) &addr,sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
      {
        printf("\n\t Bind failed with error ::%d::", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(1);
      }
      printf("\n socket %d bind to port %d\t\n", gConfiguration.sockArray[i], gConfiguration.ports[i]);
      k++;
    }  
}
void joinMCastGroup(void)
{
  struct     ip_mreq mreq = {0};
  unsigned int i=0;
  unsigned int j=0;

  mreq.imr_interface.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  for(i=0;i<gConfiguration.numSockets;i++)
  {
    //In order to be a member of multiple MGroups run a loop
    for(j=0;j<gConfiguration.numAddress;j++)
    {
      //Select MulticastGroup
      mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr=gConfiguration.address[j];

      if (setsockopt(gConfiguration.sockArray[i],IPPROTO_IP,IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,(char*)&mreq,sizeof(mreq)) < 0) 
      {
        printf("\n\t Setsocketopt IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP failed with::%d:: on ::%d:: socket",  WSAGetLastError(),j);
        exit(1);
      }
      //printf("\n %d socket is a member of the group add = %d,\n", i, gConfiguration.address[j]);
    }
  }
}

void dataRecv(void)
{
  int        retVal=-1;
  int        nBytes=-1;
  int        addrLen=0;
  char      buffer[MSG_BUF_SIZE];
  struct      sockaddr_in addr;
  fd_set      readFD;
  unsigned int  i=0;
  unsigned int    tickCount =0;

  gLastTickCount=GetTickCount();
  long lTotalPkt = 0;
  timeval timeout;
  timeout.tv_sec = 10;
  timeout.tv_usec = 100000;
  DWORD dwWaitResult = 0;
//  system("cls");
  printf("\n *********************************************** ");
  printf("\n Waiting for packets to come...");
  printf("\n ***********************************************\n ");
  addrLen=sizeof(addr);

  printf("\n Total Seq no to recv = %d\n", gTotalPkt);
  gSeqNo2 = 0;
  dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE);
  if(dwWaitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
  {
    while(1)
    {
      FD_ZERO(&readFD);
      for(i=0;i<gConfiguration.numSockets;i++)
        FD_SET(gConfiguration.sockArray[i],&readFD);

      retVal=select(FD_SETSIZE,&readFD,NULL,NULL,&timeout);

      if(0<retVal)
      {
        for(i=0;i<gConfiguration.numSockets;i++)
        {
          if(FD_ISSET(gConfiguration.sockArray[i],&readFD))
          {
            addrLen=sizeof(addr);
            if ((nBytes=recvfrom(gConfiguration.sockArray[i],buffer,sizeof(buffer),0,(struct sockaddr *) &addr,&addrLen)) < 0) 
            {
              printf("\n\t RecvFrom Error with::%d::\n", WSAGetLastError());
              exit(1);
            }
            //printf("\n recvd on socket no = %d, data=%s, address = %d\n", i, buffer, gConfiguration.address[i]);
            gSeqNo2++;
            gBytesCount++;//= nBytes;
            gTotalByteReceived += gBytesCount;
          }
        }
        //tickCount = GetTickCount();
        //if((tickCount - gLastTickCount) > 1000) //Checking if it's more than 2 seconds or not
        //{

      }
      else
      {
        printf("timeout\n");
      }
      if(gTotalPkt == gSeqNo2)
      {
        printf("\n %d packets recvd.\n", gSeqNo2);
        ReleaseMutex(mutex);
        break;
      }

    }
  }
  ReleaseMutex(mutex);

  printf("\n Total packet Received= %d\n", gSeqNo2);
}
void RecvUsingThread()
{
  int i = 0;
  gtCount = 2;
  gTotalPkt =  gConfiguration.numPacket * gConfiguration.numAddress * gConfiguration.numPorts;//atol(buffer);
  mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
  if(NULL == mutex)
  {
    printf("\nunable to create mutex.\n.");
  }
  for(i = 0;i<gtCount;i++)
  {
    threadHandle[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ( LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE )dataRecv, NULL, 0, &threadId[i]);
    if (threadHandle[i] == NULL) 
       {
          printf("Unable to create Thread\n");
       }
  }
  WaitForMultipleObjects(gtCount, threadHandle, TRUE, INFINITE);
  for(i = 0;i<gtCount;i++)
  {
    CloseHandle(threadHandle[i]);
  }

  printf("\nTotal packet recvd = %d\n", gSeqNo2);
}

void socketOperations(void)
{
  int      retVal=-1;
  WSADATA    WsaData;
  // Initialize Winsock version 2.2
  if ((retVal = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &WsaData)) != 0)
  {
    // NOTE: Since Winsock failed to load we cannot use WSAGetLastError 
       // to determine the error code as is normally done when a Winsock 
       // API fails. We have to report the return status of the function.
    printf("\n\t WSAStartup failed with error ::%d::", retVal);
       exit(1);
  }

  //Creating Sockets and setting the SO_REUSEADDR option
  socketCreation();
  //Binding Sockets
  socketBinding();
  //Joining with the Multicast Group.
  joinMCastGroup();
  //Receiving the data on a Socket.
  RecvUsingThread();
}
//100AddrOn2Ports
```

Comment: What is the question? What doesn't work?

Comment: Also note many NICs and switches have limitations on simultaneous multicast group support and such devices must be thoroughly tested before hand.

Answer (score 0):

Ports are the final destination not multicast groups.

Therefore *packet A* sent to *port 100* will reach any joined application it reaches via whatever groups it is connected to unless the platform is Windows because WinSock provides additional filtering than Unix hosts.

You must use **unique pairs of multicast group and UDP port** it is insufficient to treat the pair as a unique tuple.

Use 226.0.0.1:500, 226.0.0.2:502, etc, **do not use** 226.0.0.1:500, 226.0.0.2:500, etc.